# Stop Application

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a main function used play.core.server.ProdServerStart to start an application. Does any one know how to stop the server or let main exit gracefully? I am using play 2.4. Thanks!

Here is my main function:

```
object Test {
  def main (args: Array[String]) {
    play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(Array())
    println("Main In Test")
    println("Main finishes, want to exit")
    // How to stop?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(Array())` returns an object of type `ServerWithStop` [(source)](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-server/src/main/scala/play/core/server/ProdServerStart.scala#L38). Try assigning the result to a variable `server`, then calling `server.stop()`:

```
object Test {
  def main (args: Array[String]) {
    val server = play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(Array())
    println("Main In Test")
    println("Main finishes, want to exit")
    server.stop()
  }
}
```

Comment: ProdServerStart.main doesn't have return value.

Comment: Actually `ProdServerStart.main` method's last call is `start(process)` which returns `ServerWithStop` object. Since in Scala last expression is taken as return value `main` method should also return same object as `start` method. I wasn't testing this particular call chain myself, but I assume there should be no reason for this to work differently.